# php POST summation

Tags: php

i am sending 5 different data across to a php file through POST method. the data is all integers. i want to add up all these integer values to produce a sum.

```
    $.post(
        "user_submit.php", 
        {score: $('#ques'+qn).find('input[name=vote]:checked').val() }, 
        function(data){
            $("#ques"+qn).hide();
            ++qn;
            $("#ques"+qn).show();
        });
    });
```

in the php file:

```
$score = $_POST['score'];
$total = $total + $score;
echo $total;
```

it is not adding up the values. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show what does `print_r($_POST);` returns?

Comment: Is it that $score is wrong or that $total doesn't accumulate? Might be helpful to show more of your php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to `print_r($_POST['score'])`, you would see that it's actually an array, not a single value. Try something like `$total += array_sum($_POST['score']);` instead.

Comment: Sorry, see the other answers about decoding the JSON serialized string first. I forgot jQuery does that.

Answer (score 1):

$.post from jQuery submits a JSON encoded string to the server; you're actually submitting a javascript array which needs to be handled via `json_decode` first, and then manipulated second.

As the other posters suggested, doing a `print_r($_POST['score'])` would have shown this very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

bkuhns is on the right path. your score isnt goin gto be any array though i dont think. AFIK $.searialize isnt recusive so youre going to get a score of `'Object'`. try using this for the `data.score` key of your $.post:

```
function(){
  var score = new Array(); 
  $('#ques'+qn).find('input[name=vote]:checked').each(function(){
   score.push($(this).val());
  });
  return score.join(',');
}
```

and in php:

```
$scores = explode(',',$_POST['score']);
```

then loop through `$scores` adding to `$total`. or you could use `array_sum` as bkuhns suggests.

Comment: Yep, I forgot about the JSON serialized string part. Once the string's decoded though, `array_sum()` will be your easiest solution.