# can a POST file handle multiple requests?

Tags: php

i have a file user_submit.php that handle all the POST requests.
what i am doing is i am sending small integer values through jquery POST method. these integer values are sent one at a time around 10 times.

what i want to do is i want to add all these values up and provide a final result after the last step.

so i am doing:

```
$score = intval($_POST['score']);
$total = $total+$score;
echo $total;
```

but it fails to sum all the values up. as soon as i send the second value, the file forgets the first value. i mean the first value doesnt get stored in $total for use in the second request.

how do i go about it?

Comment: I guess you need to consider this first. How to link different POST request which is came from same user? $_SESSIONS may be what you are looking for. But i am not sure.

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104257/php-post-summation ?

Comment: Does your script only add the values? If so, you can do this in Javascript directly, no need for server side processing. Or some them up with JS first and send the result to the server if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exists because you have a wrong understanding of the whole way PHP (and other web-based languages work).

Once each PHP request is done, the application is closed, all variables are killed, etc. Therefore every time your POST request finishes, your `$total` variable is reset.

To work around this limit, PHP has a session handling mechanism that allows you to store variables session-wide, thus keeping them between the requests, but allowing them to be set uniquely for each user.

I suggest that you modify so that it uses the build-in PHP [session handling mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

```
<?php
$score = intval($_POST['score']);
$_SESSION['total'] = isset($_SESSION['total']) ? $_SESSION['total']+$score : $score;
echo $_SESSION['total];
```

You can find more examples of session variable usage in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store `$total` in a `$_SESSION` variable on the php side otherwise it gets recreated at each request.

Alternatively you could pass both score and current total via ajax.

Comment: `$total = isset($_SESSION["total"]) ? $_SESSION["total"] : 0;` - also see this http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp